# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: php, sql, symfony, symfony3, doctrine2

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO Answer
>   (name_of_answ, right, Question_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params
>   ["ок", 1, 133]:
>
> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'right,
>   Question_id) VALUES ('ок', 1, 133)' at line 1

Перечитал много форумов и везде пишут, чтоб при такой ошибке ставили скобки и всё будет окей, но запрос-то генерирую не я. 
Вот мои сущности

**Answer**:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="Answer")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Answer
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $nameOfAnsw;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $right;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Question",inversedBy="QuizQuestions")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Question_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="cascade")
     */
    private $idQuestion;

    public function getId(): int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setnameOfAnsw(string $nameOfAnswer)
    {
        $this->nameOfAnsw=$nameOfAnswer;
    }

    public function getnameOfAnsw()
    {
        return $this->nameOfAnsw;
    }

    public function setRight(bool $right)
    {
        $this->right=$right;
    }

    public function getRight()
    {
        return $this->right;
    }

    public function setIdQuestion( $idQuestion)
    {
        $this->idQuestion=$idQuestion;
    }

    public function getQuestion_id()
    {
        return $this->idQuestion;
    }
}
```

**Question:**

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="Question")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Question implements \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $Id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60, unique=false)
     */
    private $name_of_question;

    public function getId():int
    {
        return $this->Id;
    }

    public function setNameOfQuestions(string $nameOfQuestion)
    {
        $this->name_of_question=$nameOfQuestion;
    }

    public function getname_of_question()
    {
        return $this->name_of_question;
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->Id,
            $this->name_of_question,
        ));
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::unserialize() */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->Id,
            $this->name_of_question,
            ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }
}
```

И вот собственно сам контролер

```
 /**
     * @Route("/admin/questionedit/add", name="/admin/questionedit/add")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function AddAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $question= new Question();
        $question->setNameOfQuestions($_GET['questions']);
        $em->persist($question);

        $em->flush();
        $true=true;
        $false=false;
        $answer1 = new Answer();
        $answer1->setnameOfAnsw($_GET['answer1']);
        if ($_GET['trueAnswer']=="1")
        {
            $answer1->setRight('true');
        }else
        {
            $answer1->setRight('false');
        }
        $answer1->setIdQuestion($question);
        $em->persist($answer1);

        $answer2 = new Answer();
        $answer2->setnameOfAnsw($_GET['answer2']);
        if ($_GET['trueAnswer']=="2")
        {
            $answer2->setRight("$true");
        }else
        {
            $answer2->setRight("$false");
        }
        $answer2->setIdQuestion($question);
        $em->persist($answer2);

        $answer3 = new Answer();
        $answer3->setnameOfAnsw($_GET['answer3']);
        if ($_GET['trueAnswer']=="3")
        {
            $answer3->setRight("true");
        }else
        {
            $answer3->setRight("$false");
        }
        $answer3->setIdQuestion($question);
        $em->persist($answer3);


        $answer4 = new Answer();
        $answer4->setnameOfAnsw($_GET['answer4']);
        if ($_GET['trueAnswer']=="4")
        {
            $answer4->setRight("$true");
        }else
        {
            $answer4->setRight("$false");
        }
        $answer4->setIdQuestion($question);
        $em->persist($answer4);
        $em->flush();
        return new Response("Hello");
    }
```

Заранее извиняюсь за ужасно некрасивый код.
Параметры все передаёт верные. Все геты рабочие.
И вот такой запрос генерит

> INSERT INTO Answer (name_of_answ, right, Question_id) VALUES (?, ?,
>   ?)' with params ["\u043e\u043a", 1, 133]

Comment: Ну а кто додумался использовать зарезервированное слово `RIGHT` в качестве имени поля, а?

Comment: @Akina тоооочно.

Comment: На будущее. Если MySQL пишет *check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near*, то дальше цитату из запроса он начнёт ровно с того символа (слова), на котором возникла проблема. У тебя первое слово в вырезке из запроса - `right`, и именно на него надо было смотреть.